# Error destructuring optional and required properties in TS types

Tags: typescript

I am fairly new to TS and have checked out the other TS posts on here that talk about how to set up interfaces in which you have one property that you want to require and then you want to require *at least* one of two properties.

I set up my interfaces like this

```js
export interface PropertyFilterMappingBase {
    name: string
}

export interface PropertyToExclude extends PropertyFilterMappingBase {
    exclude: boolean
}

export interface PropertyToRequire extends PropertyFilterMappingBase {
    required: boolean
}

export type PropertyFilterMapping = PropertyFilterMappingBase | PropertyToExclude | PropertyToRequire;
```

So this gives me a `PropertyFilterMapping` that must include `name` and must include either `exclude` or `required`

Now I have a function that loops through these things and tries to destructure, though of course not both `exclude` and `required` would be found.

i.e. `const { name, exclude, required } = mapping`

Further down in the code, I can check what is `undefined` and handle those cases but the TS compiler is not letting me get away with this code, complaining that

`Property 'exclude' does not exist on type 'PropertyFilterMapping'.` and also 
`Property 'required' does not exist on type 'PropertyFilterMapping'.`

which makes sense but now how would I write a function that can handle these objects that may or may not have a `exclude` and / or `required` property?

Comment: Correction, I updated the interface as the last case was non-sensical, so the `(PropertyToExclude & PropertyToRequire)` makes no sense as you would never have a property mapping that is both excluded and also required... The previous last line in the interface was `export type PropertyFilterMapping = PropertyFilterMappingBase | PropertyToExclude | PropertyToRequire | (PropertyToExclude & PropertyToRequire);`

Comment: Those properties may not be present in each member of the union so it can't access them. You could try [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAdpgJ4BiwANpFALJxZagDmAQnAM4oDeAUMl8iHALYQAXMiZgodANyduEAB4JiAVwAmEAPzCARhgzEIcEFO7IoEAI6Lgp5RuTbd+w+wC+7dqDLwkaTDij4AFQwAUXklVWQ5SBBlJh9sXEISMkpqOkYWZA5jOQUVITsdPQMXNw9oLxR0BP88IIAlc0tTSNlo2Pi-fCJSaFSaEAZmNmkuUwsrCGUtIsdS9nwcTsSelKoB2mQAXmXa1b719OHkAB9dwJCw-NPzuoxGidMpdhhFEAQwYAwQZFkACj4h0GwmqXSSvQoQNoAEosqNkAhvqIsjx+BAADStPKqTHjZpTZDObbIQFpQYuIA), or update your question with a [mcve] if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a solution. Solved it with

```
export type PropertyFilterMapping = { name: string } & (
    { required: boolean, exclude?: never } | { exclude: boolean, required?: never })
```